# horizontalScroll view doesnt scroll

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have made a horizontal view and inside it one linearlayout.
XML file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >


    <ImageView 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:id="@+id/img_view" 
      />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal">
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to create 20 buttons which should scroll horizontally in horizontalScroll view but my activity just shows 4 buttons and doesnt scroll.

my code is

```
public class NumericPage extends Activity{

  private LinearLayout linear_layout;
  private HorizontalScrollView hzv;
    Button[] btn = new Button[10];
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.numericpage);
    hzv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    linear_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
    {
        btn[j] = new Button(this);
     btn[j].setText("" + j );
     btn[j].setId(j);
     btn[j].setWidth(100);
     btn[j].setHeight(40);
     linear_layout.addView(btn[j]);

    }
        }
}
```

beginnr at android.. plz help!!
thnx

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout is created outside your HorizontalScrollView, correct your layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/bg"
>


<ImageView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/img_view" 
  />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">

     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

</HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```